# Sum values from Duplicated rows

Tags: sql, group-by, row, field

There's my sql data:

```
code name total
---------------
3   Sprite 2400
17  Coke   1500
6   Dew    1000
17  Coke   3000
6   Dew    2000
```

But code and name has duplicated values and I want to sum total from each duplicated field.
Something like this:

```
code name total
---------------
3   Sprite 2400
17  Coke   4500
6   Dew    3000
```

How could I do that in sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT code, name, sum(total) AS total FROM table GROUP BY code, name
```