# Sum column's values from duplicate rows python3

Tags: sum, duplicates, row, pandas-groupby

I have a old.csv like this:

```
Name,State,Brand,Model,Price
Adam,MO,Toyota,RV4,26500
Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,18000
Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,12000
Kavin,CA,Ford,F150,23000
Yuke,OR,Nissan,Murano,31000
```

and I need a new.csv like this:

```
Name,State,Brand,Model,Price
Adam,MO,Toyota,RV4,26500
Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,30000
Kavin,CA,Ford,F150,23000
Yuke,OR,Nissan,Murano,31000
```

As you can see the difference from these two is:

Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,18000

Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,12000

```
  merge to
```

Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,30000

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('old.csv')
df1=df.sort_values('Name').groupby('Name','State','Brand','Model')
.agg({'Name':'first','Price':'sum'})
print(df1[['Name','State','Brand','Model','Price']])
```

and It didn't work,and I got these error:

> File "------\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4421, in sort_values stacklevel=stacklevel)
>     File "------- \venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1382, in _get_label_or_level_values raise KeyError(key)
>   KeyError: 'Name'

I am a totally new of python,and I found a solutions in stackoverflow:

[Sum values from Duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793063/sum-values-from-duplicated-rows)

The site above has similar question as mine,But It's a sql code,
Not Python

Any help will be great appreciation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('old.csv')
```

Group by 4 fields(`'Name', 'State', 'Brand', 'Model'`) and select `Price` column and apply aggregate `sum` to it,

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Name', 'State', 'Brand', 'Model'])['Price'].agg(['sum'])
print(df1)
```

This will give you a required output,

```
                                  sum
Name    State   Brand    Model  
Adam    MO     Toyota    RV4     26500
Berry   KS     Toyota    Camry   30000
Kavin   CA     Ford      F150    23000
Yuke    OR     Nissan    Murano  31000
```

Note: There is only column `sum` in this `df1`. All 4 other columns are indexes so to convert it into csv, we first need to convert these 4 index columns to dataframe columns.

`list(df1['sum'].index.get_level_values('Name'))` will give you an output like this,

`['Adam', 'Berry', 'Kavin', 'Yuke']`

Now, for all indexes, do this,

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
cols = ['Name', 'State', 'Brand', 'Model']
for col in cols:
    df2[col] = list(df1['sum'].index.get_level_values(col))
df2['Price'] = df1['sum'].values
```

Now, just write df2 to excel file like this,

```
df2.to_csv('new.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation,there are very clear and useful

Comment: May I ask if these two rows of data are not quit similar or not duplicate ,like maybe only half of values are same,How can I ignore the different part base on 2, or 3 same values in rows and get the same result as above?for instance,Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,18000
Berry,KS,?,?,12000  merge into Berry,KS,Toyota,Camry,30000 ?

Comment: You have to do something like this,
df.groupby(['Name', 'State'])['Price'].agg(['sum'])
this will give you a sum column with two index columns. Now you can extract 3 columns from this dataframe by applying same technique which I applied in above answer and extract other two columns from original dataframe. Hopefully, this will work!

Comment: Thank you again! I used just like this;                                                                
aggregation_functions={'State':'first','Brand':'first','Model':'first','Price':'sum'}                df2=df.groupby(df['Name']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)                                  And It is what I want...